# Dad's phone will not connect to certain web sites, and certain apps will not logon at his house, but work at mine

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android, blocking

So, I bought my dad a new Motorola G7 Power phone to replace his old phone. Since he doesn't want to pay for data — and the plan's expense is mainly data — I have his data plan connection turned off. He normally gets Internet from Wi-Fi through his router. His old phone was configured the same way.

After having the new phone a week or so, we found that some — but not all — web sites seem to be inaccessible, and some phone apps fail to login. He is using Google Chrome for Android, v 77.0.3865.92 and the OS is Android 9.

His other phone had no such issues with the same apps and sites. My phone connects to those seemingly blocked websites with no issues on his network. His Chromebook and Windows 10 laptop have no issues on the same websites.

We are located in the southern United States and the odd assortment of inaccessible sites are mainly:

- Twitter (`twitter.com`)
- Kroger (`kroger.com`)
- Home Depot (`homedepot.com`)

Sites that *are* accessible:

- Facebook (`facebook.com`)
- Google (`google.com`)
- Others

I feared malware, because I let Google restore the apps he used on his old phone. However, I brought his new phone to my house, to connect to my Wi-Fi, and now, all the blocked websites and apps work just fine.

This sounds like his router blocking certain sites, however, no changes have been made to his router (he wouldn't know how and no one else at the house knows anything about that kind of stuff). I haven't had time to go back and load the router's admin page to look around, but highly doubt any web address blocking, mainly because no other devices are blocked. Just this one.

This makes no sense. Any ideas out there??

Comment: Did you see this other question and answer thread? https://superuser.com/q/468804/167207

Comment: What do you mean they seem to be inaccessible? What happens when you go to the websites?

Comment: Page never loads. Like the URL is blocked. The Kroger and Twitter apps both timeout while attempting to authenticate.

Comment: What browser are you using on the phone? Is it some built in Motorola browser or something else? Reply back with @DrZoo so I get pinged about your reply.

Comment: @JakeGould, that's an intriguing solution, however, while I can't confirm his exact setup at the moment (he lives in another town, and it's too late to catch him), but I feel quite certain that the only router is an ADSL "Gateway" router/modem combo, that hasn't changed config in years, and that no other router is directly connected to the gateway.

Comment: @DrZoo, the mobile browser is Google Chrome for Android, v 77.0.3865.92. OS is Android 9.

Comment: This sounds less like blocking and perhaps more like pages being unable fully load due to a weak signal. But that is just a guess.